# Not able to switch to branch due to changes to hidden files?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm still fairly new with using Git inside of Visual Studio and I'm having a problem trying to switch from my Master to a Branch I created. I have a screen shot of the message from the Output window.

I've tried committing everything from the top level of the project inside VS but it shows nothing to commit. Any ideas on how I can get past these errors? I'm ultimately trying to merge my Branch into the Master.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I followed the following article and added a .gitignore through Visual Studio. I see that it put the file on my local folder system but not on the remote repository which would expect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branches?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio

However, now when I try to switch to my branch I get the following error about changes to the .gitignore and the .csproj.user file. I went to the remote repository and deleted both of the .csproj files but that didn't help. I need the file locally so I'm not sure what else it's looking for. I looked to see if anything was not committed and it looks as though everything is.

[image]

Comment: Use `.gitignore` file to ignore `.vs` and `bin` and `obj` directories. They don't belong in the repository anyway.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into what to do with that.

Comment: If you use a `.gitignore` you'll also need to remove the newly ignored files. Otherwise you'll still have this issue.

Comment: Added the .gitignore file but still not able to switch branches. I added an update to the original post if anyone has any ideas on what I can do.